# Is there a better way to check status of windows service on remote server

Tags: java

I have a java function that takes the server IP and checks the status of a particular windows service on that server (Running or Stopped). When checking the status of the service on the server where code is running, it runs in seconds. But, while checking the status of the service on another server (remote server) in same domain, it takes a lot of time.

Is there any better way to perform this task? Below is the function that I am using.

```
public boolean checkService(String PSIP) {
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sc \\\\" + PSIP + " query smpolicysrv");

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            //System.out.println(line+"\n");
            if (line.trim().startsWith("STATE"))
            {

                if (line.trim().substring(line.trim().indexOf(":") + 1, line.trim().indexOf(":") + 4).trim().equals("1")) {
                    System.out.println("Stopped");
                    return false;
                } else
                if (line.trim().substring(line.trim().indexOf(":") + 1, line.trim().indexOf(":") + 4).trim().equals("2"))
                    System.out.println("Startting....");
                else
                if (line.trim().substring(line.trim().indexOf(":") + 1, line.trim().indexOf(":") + 4).trim().equals("3"))
                    System.out.println("Stopping....");
                else
                if (line.trim().substring(line.trim().indexOf(":") + 1, line.trim().indexOf(":") + 4).trim().equals("4")) {
                    System.out.println("Running");
                    return true;
                }
            }
            line = reader.readLine();
        }

    } catch (IOException e1) {}
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Try any RPC model? Instead of direct contact?

Comment: Kris - can you kindly provide an example.